# Sharedpeferences disappear

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

So,I'm trying to make shared preferences work in normal way, like keep some data after the app is closed, but it keeps disappearing after i launch the app 3rd time since putting data in sharedpref. I put some strings in onPause :

```
   @Override
protected void onPause(){

    sharedpref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putString("uzytkownik1", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik2", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz2"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik3", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz3"));
    editor.putString("uzytkownik4", getIntent().getStringExtra("nazwauz4"));
    editor.putString("haslo1", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy1"));
    editor.putString("haslo2", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy2"));
    editor.putString("haslo3", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy3"));
    editor.putString("haslo4", getIntent().getStringExtra("haslouzy4"));
    editor.apply();

    super.onPause();
}
```

And then I want them to appear when you get back to the app, I did it in onResume like this :

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {

    sharedpref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik1", null) != null || sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik2", null) != null || sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik3", null) != null || sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik4", null) != null) {
        user1.setText(sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik1", null));
        user2.setText(sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik2", null));
        user3.setText(sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik3", null));
        user4.setText(sharedpref.getString("uzytkownik4", null));
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

But as i said, it's disappearing after 3rd launch, after created account. What is the problem ?

Comment: that is a little strange. Do one thing print Log to check the value of every launch and closing the app.

Comment: remove duplicate init for "sharedpref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);"

call this line from oncreate once

Comment: @Akarsh M how should i do this?

Comment: What should i look for in the log?